# Manually setting one chapter number in memoir

Tags: chapters, memoir

I need to insert a chapter 7.5 between chapters 7 and 8.  I've figured out how to get chapter 8 to be chapter 8, but I can't figure out how to get chapter 7.5 to be chapter 7.5.  I'm using the memoir.cls and chapterstyle "dash".

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\chapterstyle{dash}

\begin{document}

\chapter{The Laboratory} %This is the chapter I want labelled 7.5

\setcounter{chapter}{7}
\chapter{Testing} %This is the chapter I want to be labelled "8".
\end{document}
```

Thanks!

Comment: David has provided a simple and effective solution. I'd add that having a chapter numbered "7.5" might be a bad idea *if* chapter 7 has numbered sections. Because "7.5" would then be ambiguous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\chapterstyle{dash}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand\thechapter{7.5}
\chapter{The Laboratory} %This is the chapter I want labelled 7.5
\renewcommand\thechapter{\arabic{chapter}}

\setcounter{chapter}{7}
\chapter{Testing} %This is the chapter I want to be labelled "8".
\end{document}
```

Comment: Beat me by a few seconds :)